# could not get the persisted sequence number from db after save and flush in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have a table with composite primary key as `sequence number, id` for a table ... let's say `parent_tbl`.

This `sequence number is an oracle seq number that is generated with a trigger before insert` on each row.

We have another table, let's call it `child_tbl` with a `uni-directional many-to-one association to parent_tbl`.

after persisting the parent_tbl. it `returns sequence number as 0.`

But, I need the sequence number for persisting child_tbl, otherwise, it returns integrity constraint (*_FK1) violated - parent key not found.

I am currently using spring data jpa. `How can I retrieve the sequence number`?

Comment: Assuming you are checking the managed entity after the commit, You need to configure your JPA provider so that it knows to read back the id from the inserted entity so it can be used in foreign keys.  What provider are you using? And why use a composite pk and trigger when a single field with a standard sequence might suffice?

Comment: It is a legacy system where the sequence is set by a trigger and we have a new table that has the parent as parent_tbl. How do I configure spring data jpa to return sequence number? It is currently returning 0 even after flush and also as a separate tx.

Comment: https://forums.netbeans.org/topic13007.html I will try this and will let you know. Thanks